# SQL: How do dynamically parse ranges from min to next min?

Tags: sql, range, pivot

I am trying to figure out how (or see if possible) I can grab the minimum value of 'TEST' and get just the next minimum value of 'TEST', then join again and go after the 2nd minimum value, etc, etc.

Table1

```
ID  TEST
A12 1
A12 2
A12 3
A12 5
A12 8
B35 1
B35 3
```

Results I'm after:

```
ID  RANGE1  RANGE2
A12 1   2
A12 2   3
A12 3   5
A12 5   8
B35 1   3
```

table code I'm using:

```
WITH FRED AS
(
SELECT  'A12' AS ID
    , 1 AS TEST
UNION
SELECT  'A12' AS ID
    , 2 AS TEST
UNION   
SELECT  'A12' AS ID
    , 3 AS TEST
UNION   
SELECT  'B35' AS ID
    , 1 AS TEST
UNION   
SELECT  'B35' AS ID
    , 2 AS TEST
)
SELECT  *
FROM    FRED F
```

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: How do you want to handle it if there are repeating values for each ID? For example, what if there are two rows with the same ID and TEST values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
--Construct sample data.
WITH FRED AS
(
SELECT  'A12' AS ID
    , 1 AS TEST
UNION
SELECT  'A12' AS ID
    , 2 AS TEST
UNION   
SELECT  'A12' AS ID
    , 3 AS TEST
UNION
SELECT  'A12' AS ID
    , 5 AS TEST
UNION
SELECT  'A12' AS ID
    , 8 AS TEST
UNION   
SELECT  'B35' AS ID
    , 1 AS TEST
UNION   
SELECT  'B35' AS ID
    , 3 AS TEST
),

--This is the sample data
test_data AS
(
SELECT  *
FROM    FRED F
ORDER BY ID, TEST
)

SELECT  td.ID, td.TEST as RANGE1, MIN(td2.TEST) as RANGE2

FROM    test_data td
    cross join test_data td2

WHERE   td.ID = td2.ID
    AND
    td.TEST < td2.TEST

GROUP BY    td.ID, td.TEST

ORDER BY td.ID, td.TEST
```

test_data gives the sample you provided. I can try to handle repeated value cases once you let us all know how you want those to be handled. The current code above doesn't do that.

Comment: Just a note, if there are repeated values in the data, my code right now will ignore them.

Comment: Thanks so much! That was what I'm after! =)

Comment: No worries. Happy to help =)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is mysql (but most other DBMS will do the same) you can join the table with itself and use the limit in the ON clause.

Minima and grouping helps you from there.

e.g.:

```
mysql> SELECT m.id, m.test AS RANGE1 ,min(mm.test) AS RANGE2 
       FROM table1 AS m
       INNER JOIN table1 AS mm ON m.id=mm.id AND mm.test > m.test 
       GROUP BY m.id,m.test;
+------+--------+--------+
| id   | RANGE1 | RANGE2 |
+------+--------+--------+
| a12  |      1 |      2 |
| a12  |      2 |      3 |
| a12  |      3 |      5 |
| a12  |      5 |      8 |
| b35  |      1 |      3 |
+------+--------+--------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Take care with the efficiency of these things.

You might need to look into how to deal with edge cases where no second value is present in the table.

See also here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24014/how-do-i-get-the-current-and-next-greater-value-in-one-select